# Is it expected to get NPE on isAutoCommit or getUpdate on a fresh Session object in MarkLogic 9?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Under MarkLogic XCC version 9.0-3, I get a NullPointerException when trying to call `isAutoCommit` or `getUpdate` on a fresh Session object.

The NPE does *not* occur if either `setAutoCommit` or `setUpdate` is called first. Is this intentional behavior? If so, why? All other getters for Session return without error even if no value is set.

I've constructed a minimal viable example:

```
import java.net.URI;

import com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSource;
import com.marklogic.xcc.ContentSourceFactory;
import com.marklogic.xcc.Session;

public class mve {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("usage: xcc://user:password@host:port/contentbase");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Running minimal viable example of MarkLogic isAutoCommit/getUpdate bug...");

        URI uri = new URI(args[0]);
        ContentSource contentSource = ContentSourceFactory.newContentSource(uri);
        Session updateSession = contentSource.newSession();

        // comment out the following two lines to cause a NullPointerException to be thrown on getUpdate and isAutoCommit:
        updateSession.setAutoCommit(false);
        updateSession.setUpdate(Session.Update.TRUE);

        System.out.println("is AutoCommit?");
        System.out.println(updateSession.isAutoCommit()); // if lines 21 and 22 are both commented out, this will cause NPE

        System.out.println("getUpdate?");
        System.out.println(updateSession.getUpdate());  // if lines 21 and 22 are both commented out, this will cause NPE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of those methods attempt to access properties of the TransactionMode, which is null.

Invoking either [`setAutoCommit()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-) or [`setUpdate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#setUpdate-com.marklogic.xcc.Session.Update-), or explicitly setting the TransactionMode with [`setTransactionMode()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html#setTransactionMode-com.marklogic.xcc.Session.TransactionMode-) will ensure that the `txnMode` is not `null`.

If you upgrade to 9.0.4, the SessionImpl `isAutoCommit()` will return a default `true` without an NPE:

```
public boolean isAutoCommit() {
    return txnMode == null ? true : txnMode.isAutoCommit();
}
```

but you will still get an NPE if you invoke `getUpdate()` without a `txnMode` being established:

```
public Update getUpdate() {
    return txnMode.getUpdate();
}
```

It is probably reasonable to expect that it return a default `TransactionMode.AUTO` instead of an NPE.

Comment: I notice that the change to `isAutoCommit` behavior is unfortunately not documented in the [9.0-4 release notes](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap3#id_29897).